# How can I modify my website so that it contains variable containers for content?

Tags: frontend, web-hosting, backend

I'm sorry, i'm really new to making websites. I wrote the index.html, main.css and the js file for some functionality, but what i'd really like to do is add a variable in the html file instead of having many image tags. So that there is just one variable that will take care of however much images the user decides to upload. 
I'm doing this for a friend, and she's not familiar with any technical stuff, so i'm thinking what would be easier is if she just uses a file manager and uploads all the photos into one folder, and the source files do the rest automatically (arrange each photos on the page). With my limited understanding of back-end development, i'm guessing this is some code i have to write on the server?

Could you please give me some pointers or illuminate me in how to do this? I googled this a lot, and maybe i'm not phrasing the question correctly, but nothing comes up. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an out of the box online [CMS (Content Management System)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Software_as_a_service_.28SaaS.29) that is modular.  My personal favorite is [WordPress](https://wordpress.com/), and there are many other managed web-hosting products out there that will do what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there by any chance another way of doing this aside from using CMS? My friend doesn't want to use wordpress for some reasons...

Comment: Pick another CMS from the list that fits the user requirements.  A little Googling will reveal many options: http://www.cmswire.com/cms/web-cms/7-rules-for-selecting-the-right-content-management-system-023026.php.